# How to convert key: "value" to key:["value"] in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, key-value

I have a list of objects in which I get a key value pair that look something like this :

```
Object {
  key1 : "value1",
  key2 : ["value2", "value3", "value4"], 
  key3 : ["value5", "value6"],
  key4 : "value7",
  .
  .
}
```

I'm printing these values in a loop as this:

```
Object.key1[i], Object.key2[i], Object.key3[i]...
```

As you can see for key1[i] it will print "v" since its not an array.
How do I convert those string values and  overwrite the same object?

This is how I want the object to look like after overwriting :

```
Object {
  key1 : ["value1"],
  key2 : ["value2", "value3", "value4"], 
  key3 : ["value5", "value6"],
  key4 : ["value7"],
  .
  .
}
```

Comment: you need to share more details, are key1 and key4 values always a string?

Comment: @sonali , No there they don't necessarily have to be strings. But I have got the answer now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the object entries. If the value isn't an array, replace it with a one-element array containing the value.

```
Object.entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
        Object[key] = [value];
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Barmar !, I used a minor different version of your snippet and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

Iterate on your object and if not array then make it an array

```
const obj = {
  key1 : "value1",
  key2 : ["value2", "value3", "value4"], 
  key3 : ["value5", "value6"],
  key4 : "value7",
  .
  .
} 

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  const value = obj[key]
  if(!Array.isArray(v) {
    obj[key] = [v]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use `typeof` to check whether the value is a string or not.

```js
if (typeof obj.key1 === 'string') // do something with it....
```

Because what's happening now is you're doing `obj.key1[i]` on a string, and you're getting not the entry `i` from the array, but instead you're getting character `i` from the string.

But there are other issues with your code, like `Object` is a reserved word, and you have no equals sign to assign your values to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Just map the object and create a shallow copy of it (e.g. via reduce)

```js
const valuesToArray = (object) => Object.entries(object).reduce(
  (result, [key, value]) => ({
    [key]: Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value],
     ...result,
   }),
   {},
)

const test = { a: 'a', b: ['b', 'b'], c: 'ccccc' }
console.log(valuesToArray(test))
```